# Content modification for date within the file

Tags: .net, windows, date, powershell

I have the following log content and I am trying to push the content into the file and modify the date time in the same file using the code below. The problem I have is only one record is inserted and modified with the date but not the successive records. I could not make the content as a string because I am modifying with the timestamp. Any suggestions, please? 
I am using PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 2008 and 2003 Servers.

```
$PATH = "C:\Tests\Content.txt"
Clear-Content $PATH

$date = [DateTime]::Now.AddHours(0).AddMinutes(0).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm")

$content = $date + ":21,900 [ListenerThread0] WARN  luminous.Core.Server.States.InvalidIPRangeState - Begin 'InvalidIPRangeState' for Device '|did:N/A^ep:10.160.210.222:40534^iprg:N/A|'"
$date + ":21,900 [ListenerThread0] INFO  luminous.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:02.16.210.222:40534^iprg:N/A|: Connection Established"
$date + ":49,993 [12 ] INFO  luminous.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:02.16.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|: Connection Rejected.  Reason: Socket closed by remote party"
$date + ":49,994 [ListenerThread0] WARN  luminous.Core.Server.States.InvalidIPRangeState - Begin 'InvalidIPRangeState' for Device '|did:N/A^ep:02.16.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|'"
$date + ":49,994 [ListenerThread0] INFO  luminous.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:02.16.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|: Connection Sustained"

Add-Content -Value $content -Path $PATH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your content in an array like this:

```
$PATH = "C:\Tests\Content.txt"
Clear-Content $PATH
$date = [DateTime]::Now.AddHours(0).AddMinutes(0).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm")

$content = @($date + ":21,900 [ListenerThread0] WARN  luminous.Core.Server.States.InvalidIPRangeState - Begin 'InvalidIPRangeState' for Device '|did:N/A^ep:10.160.210.222:40534^iprg:N/A|'"
$date + ":21,900 [ListenerThread0] INFO  luminous.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:02.16.210.222:40534^iprg:N/A|: Connection Established"
$date + ":49,993 [12 ] INFO  luminous.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:02.16.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|: Connection Rejected.  Reason: Socket closed by remote party"
$date + ":49,994 [ListenerThread0] WARN  luminous.Core.Server.States.InvalidIPRangeState - Begin 'InvalidIPRangeState' for Device '|did:N/A^ep:02.16.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|'"
$date + ":49,994 [ListenerThread0] INFO  luminous.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:02.16.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|: Connection Sustained")

Add-Content -Value $content -Path $PATH
```